# Почему счётчик перемещается вниз?

Tags: битрикс, реклама, счетчики

В битриксе в админке выбрано "Переместить весь Javascript в конец страницы" 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

в результате счётчик LiveInternet перемещается куда-то вниз, почти перед тегом body. А если убрать в админке "Переместить весь Javascript в конец страницы" то естественно код счётчика стоит на месте.
Код счётчика примерно такой:

```
<!--LiveInternet counter--><script type="text/javascript"><!--
document.write("<a href='http://www.liveinternet.ru/click' "+
"target=_blank><img src='//counter.yadro.ru/..."+
escape(document.referrer)+((typeof(screen)=="undefined")?"":
"...+
"' alt='' title='LiveInternet' "+
"border='0' width='31' height='31'><\/a>")
//--></script><!--/LiveInternet-->
```

Можно ли как-то переписать данный код счётчика, чтобы не перемещался вниз?
`document.write()` это вроде как устарелый вариант.
Что посоветуете?

Comment: а сам код просто htmlкой прописан в хэдере? или вставляете путем `php`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для запрета переноса существует специальный параметр для тега script

```
<script data-skip-moving="true">

</script>
```